# Assume that if in the power series expansion(around $0$) of $p(z)/q(z)$ all the coefficients of power series are integer then $q(z) \in \mathbb Z[z]$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm reading a paper in which following result is left by saying that its an easy exercise but I'm finding it a bit hard.Can someone give some ideas to complete this problem?

Let $p(z),q(z) \in \mathbb Q[z]$ be two coprime polynomials and $q(0)=1$.Further Assume that if in the power series expansion(around $0$) of $p(z)/q(z)$ all the coefficients of power series are integer then $q(z) \in \mathbb Z[z]$.

Is this problem a corollary/easy application of some "big" theorem?

Comment: This is a result of Fatou (1904). See https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fatou_ring

Comment: @Kelenner Thank you.Best Regards,